# How to set StackedBar position using High chart property?

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, stacked-chart

I need to move/Set Stacked bar position in Stacked bar chart using High Chart  property. Here is the reference image below:

[image]

I have tried with something like,`plotOptions.series.pointWidth :35`
Look like above.i need to change the bar position .
 which High chart property I need to use ? I know its due to xAxis problem.
Can anyone know **how to set stacked bar starting point/ position using high chart** property? thanks in advance.

Comment: In Highcharts, when setting data you have: `series: [{ data: [ [x, y] ] }]`, x-value is the place on xAxis. Note: Highcharts != Jaspersoft..

Comment: Hi Pawel Fus.thanks for your response.I am using Jaspersoft only.Can you know how to don in Jaspersoft?

Comment: Unfortunatetly, I have no idea.